# Guess the Disney song from the initials number 4

Tags: music

Try and guess the disney song from the initials of the lyrics.
T A O A T
T A I C B
B E F
T S B
U
J A L C
S T S T L
B A L S
N O P
B A T B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This song is a classic (and one of my favourites!):

> Beauty and the Beast!

Comment: well done p.s. who is your favourite artist/band

Comment: I'm a big fan of 50s-60s-70s-80s music myself (Eagles, John Denver, Billy Joel, Neil Diamond, Beatles, Platters, etc.), but I've recently enjoyed watching Disney movies again -- this song was in a movie I watched very recently!

Comment: OK I'll see what i can do

Comment: Haha you don't have to create a puzzle around my musical tastes! If you're enjoying Disney puzzles, I'm enjoying answering them, @WilliamPennanti

Comment: I really like the beatles would you like some of their songs doing

Comment: @WilliamPennanti I'm honestly happy with whichever songs you feel like creating! I'm just the humble solver, but you're the creative mind!

Comment: @WilliamPennanti Pls Mark the answer as correct if you feel so!

Comment: Ok. I'll do all that now